# Resource Qualifier for an Android app running in Chrome

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-resources, google-chrome-arc

I've successfully run my application in Chrome with ARC Welder. My notifications with actions is also shown really good. My problem is the color of the action item icons.

Since notifications are dark in below Lollipop, actions are white. Since notifications are light in Lollipop, actions should be grey.

In Chrome, notification and the actions are both white. You can see it below: (The icon next to "Stop" is white)

[image: Notification in Chrome]

Is there a resource qualifier like `drawable-arc` to set the icon icon in Chrome directly?

BTW, It can programatically be done like below but it messes up with my codebase.

```
if ("chromium".equals(Build.BRAND) && "chromium".equals(Build.MANUFACTURER)) {
    //Set notification action icon resource. 
}
```

**Edit:** It looks like current ARC is based on KitKat.

[image: KitKat Dialog.]

Comment: This feels like a bug. If ARC is going to ship with pre-21, it should follow pre-21 styling rules for notifications. Now, it's possible that by the time ARC goes final, that it will be running Android 5.x, in which case this particular problem goes away.

Comment: I think you are right. The ripple effects are also gone on ARC. So it is definitely pre-21. But notifications on Chrome are usually light. This will go away once it runs on Lollipop. But separate resource qualifier for ARC would be cool and useful for lots of use cases.

Comment: "So it is definitely pre-21" -- ARC reports 19 in `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`.